# Select Random Value from Pandas list column for each row ensuring that value don't get picked again

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame below

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
'poc':["a", "b", "c", "d"],
'school':["school1", "school2", "school3", "school4"],
'volunteers':[["sam", "mat", "ali", "mike", "guy", "john"], 
["sam", "mat", "ali", "mike"], ["rose", "sam", "mike", "jorge"], 
["susan", "jack", "alex", "mat", "mike"]]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) ​
```

I need to create a new column that has a random pick from the volunteers column to select 1 volunteer for each school ensuring that the same volunteer doesn't get picked twice

so far I have tried

```
import random
df["random_match"] = [random.choice(x) for x in df["volunteers"]]
```

but this just gives me a random pick without ensuring it is not repeated.

Comment: Could you add your required output?

Comment: Aren't pandas/python programming questions best asked on stackoverflow? You'll get a million times more exposure. From the FAQ: "If you think a question is equally appropriate on multiple sites, ask on the site with the most users "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a first approach, and even though this is not the best in terms of performance it makes the work:

```
def urandom(frame):
    ls = list()
    for idx, row in frame.iterrows():
        val = np.random.choice(frame.loc[idx,"volunteers"])
        while val in ls:
            val = np.random.choice(frame.loc[idx,"volunteers"])
        ls.append(val)
    
    return pd.Series(ls)


df.assign(pick = urandom(df))
```

**Outputs:** (If you need reproducible code dot not forget to add a random seed)

[image]